# OpenPyXL do not save VBA controlls

Tags: python-3.x, excel, linux, openpyxl

I have a xlsm template file with simple VBA for [type ahead drop down](https://www.contextures.com/xldataval11.html). After I save file drop down is gone.
[Error screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAuFx.png)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
    
wb = load_workbook('template.xlsm', read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
wb.save('modified.xlsm')
```

As I understand openpyxl is the only library that works with XLSM files on Linux so is there any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution that worked for me.

Simply replaced some VBA lines of code from this:

```
Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
```

Into this:

```
If ws.OLEObjects.Count = 0 Then
    Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1")
    cboTemp.Name = "TempCombo"
Else
    Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects(1)
End If
```